# Use group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Query:

```
  SELECT sd.ident,sd.suniq, testc, subtestc, ts.testscore, 
         metadept, ts.takendt, 
         MAX(takendt) testdate
    FROM studemo sd, stutests ts, testdef td, udefstu ud
   WHERE ts.suniq =sd.suniq
     AND td.testuniq = ts.testuniq
     AND ts.suniq = ud.suniq
     AND td.testuniq IN ('2000089', '2000090', '2000091', '2000092')
GROUP BY sd.suniq
ORDER BY suniq
```

get the following error :

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Column 'studemo.ident' is invalid in
>   the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause.

My goal is to have the most current test score. I am successful until I try to add more tables to include more student information.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to add those columns that aren't in the aggregate function into your `GROUP BY` in order for your SQL statement to be valid.

`GROUP BY sd.ident,sd.suniq, testc, subtestc, ts.testscore, metadept, ts.takendt`

Answer (score 3):

```
select sd.ident,sd.suniq, testc, subtestc, ts.testscore, metadept, ts.takendt, max(takendt)testdate
from studemo sd, stutests ts, testdef td, udefstu ud
where ts.suniq =sd.suniq
and td.testuniq = ts.testuniq
and ts.suniq = ud.suniq
and td.testuniq IN ('2000089', '2000090', '2000091', '2000092')
group by sd.ident,sd.suniq, testc, subtestc, ts.testscore, metadept, ts.takendt
order by suniq
```

comment: the code above is what  @Neil means

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you want to show the max takendt for each student even if they have taken multiple tests, e.g. if they have taken two tests then you want to show both test dates and in each row show the max date as well. If that is the case, then grouping by all of the other columns won't help. Maybe try this, assuming SQL Server 2005 or later:

```
        WITH md AS
        (
            SELECT ts.suniq, maxdate = MAX(ts.takendt)
                FROM dbo.stutests AS ts
            INNER JOIN
                dbo.testdef AS td
                ON td.testuniq = ts.testuniq
            WHERE
                td.testuniq IN ('2000089', '2000090', '2000091', '2000092')
            GROUP BY ts.suniq
        )
        SELECT
            sd.ident,
            sd.suniq,
            testc, -- which table does this come from? why no prefix?
            subtestc, -- which table does this come from? why no prefix?
            ts.testscore,
            metadept, -- which table does this come from? why no prefix?
            ts.takendt,
            md.maxdate
        FROM
            dbo.studemo AS sd
        INNER JOIN
            dbo.stutests AS ts
            ON sd.suniq = ts.suniq
        INNER JOIN
            dbo.testdef AS td
            ON td.testuniq = ts.testuniq
        INNER JOIN
            dbo.udefstu AS ud
            ON ts.suniq = ud.suniq
        INNER JOIN md
            ON md.suniq = sd.suniq
        WHERE
            td.testuniq IN ('2000089', '2000090', '2000091', '2000092')
        ORDER BY
            sd.suniq; -- you forgot a prefix here too
            -- could cause problems if you change the query later
```

Comment: I changed my query following these suggestions: You will need to add those columns that aren't in the aggregate function into your GROUP BY in order for your SQL statement to be valid.

GROUP BY sd.ident,sd.suniq, testc, subtestc, ts.testscore, metadept, ts.takendt

Comment: Ok, I suspect the results will not be ideal (since there will be a row for every permutation of all those column values), but who knows...

Comment: My testuniq indicates the level of test taken. Once the level is passed the student takes the next level test. So when I run the query I see the result for all levels when I just want to see the last test taken.  Is there a way I can modify the query to do that???

Comment: You'll need to provide some sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your remaining fields not using an aggregate function to your `Group By`.

```
    select sd.ident,sd.suniq, testc, subtestc, ts.testscore, metadept, ts.takendt, max(takendt)testdate
from studemo sd, stutests ts, testdef td, udefstu ud
where ts.suniq =sd.suniq
and td.testuniq = ts.testuniq
and ts.suniq = ud.suniq
and td.testuniq IN ('2000089', '2000090', '2000091', '2000092')
group by sd.suniq, sd.ident, testc, subtestc, ts.testscore, metadept, ts.takendt
order by suniq
```